# Como fazer com que uma conexão ssh se auto reconecte após um erro de broken pipe?

Tags: linux, ssh

No meu trabalho eu preciso estar o tempo todo conectado à uma máquina remota via ssh, mas ultimamente a conexão tem caído de 5 em 5 minutos e é uma tarefa muito entediante ficar reconectando. Existe uma maneira de fazer com que a conexão se auto reconecte **no mesmo estado** em que ela estava quando a conexão foi cancelada?

Comment: Tente o KiTTY (http://kitty.9bis.net/), ele é um fork do PuTTY, e tem a função de reconectar. Fonte: https://superuser.com/a/403327/442471

Comment: No link que você forneceu: KiTTY is only designed for the Microsoft® Windows® platform.

Comment: Voce pode alterar o `ConnectTimeout` do `ssh_config` para prolongar o período de conectividade com o servidor via SSH. Não é uma boa prática, mas pode resolver o seu problema. Informações mais detalhadas pode encontrar nesse Link - https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Acesso-remoto-OpenSSH-SSH-VNC-RDP-Telnet-TeamViewer-etc./Write-failed-Broken-pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar o `ConnectTimeout` do `ssh_config` encontrado em `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` para prolongar o período de conectividade com o servidor via SSH alterando seu tempo para `9999999`. Não é uma boa prática, mas pode resolver o seu problema. Feito isso, reinicie o serviço `SSH` `service sshd restart` ou `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`. Informações mais detalhadas pode encontrar nesse [Link](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Acesso-remoto-OpenSSH-SSH-VNC-RDP-Telnet-TeamViewer-etc./Write-failed-Broken-pipe)